# Rails ActiveRecord::Relationと配列を結合したい

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

ひとつはDog、もうひとつはRegistration_numberというmodelをそれぞれ以下のように作成してます。
`dog.rb`

```rb
class Dog < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :registration_numbers, dependent: :destroy
 end
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: dogs
#
#  id            :bigint           not null, primary key
#  name          :string           not null
#  created_at    :datetime         not null
#  updated_at    :datetime         not null
#  user_id       :bigint           not null
#
# Indexes
#
#  index_dogs_on_user_id  (user_id)
#
# Foreign Keys
#
#  fk_rails_...  (user_id => users.id)
#
```

`registration_number.rb`

```rb
class RegistrationNumber < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :dog
end
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: registration_numbers
#
#  id                  :bigint           not null, primary key
#  a                   :string          
#  registration_number :string           not null
#  created_at          :datetime         not null
#  updated_at          :datetime         not null
#  dog_id              :bigint           not null
#
# Indexes
#
#  index_registration_numbers_on_dog_id  (dog_id)
#
# Foreign Keys
#
#  fk_rails_...  (dog_id => dogs.id)
#
```

現状、Dogについてはcurrent_userに紐づいたものを`@dogs`として、RegistrationNumberについては、@dogsに紐づいたもので、aカラムの条件がAのものを@registration_numbersとしてそれぞれ以下のように取得してます。

```rb
# @dogs
    @dogs = Dog.where(user_id: current_user.id)
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Dog id: 1, name: ... , #<Dog id: 12, name: ... ]>

# @registration_numbers
@registration_numbers = []
    @dogs.each do |dog|
      registration_number = RegistrationNumber.where(dog_id: dog.id).merge(RegistrationNumber.where(a: 'A'))
      @registration_numbers += registration_number
=> [#<RegistrationNumber id: ... >, #<RegistrationNumber id: ... >]
```

上記の通り、@dogsについては、ActiveRecord::Relation形式で、@registration_numbersは配列で取得しています。
やりたいことは、`@dogs`に`@registration_numbers`中のカラムのひとつであるregistration_numberを結合して、
`@dogs.registration_number`の記載でview上に表示できるようにしたいです。
どのようにすればよいかちょっと検討がつかずに困っています。
何かアイデアをご教授いただければ有り難いです。

Comment: やりたいこととして「@dogs.registration_numberの記載でview上に表示できるようにしたいです。」とありますが、 Dog has_many registration_numbers なので
@dogs.registration_number は矛盾しています(複数形・単数形に着目してください)

やりたいことは「ユーザに紐づく RegistrationNumber をDog 毎に表示したい」って事かな...

Comment: ちなみに結合した結果のクラスはどっちをイメージしていますか?
ActiveRecord::Relation ? それとも配列?
例えば後者に無理やりやると ActiveRecord::Relation に `.to_a` メソッドがあるので
`@dogs.to_a` で配列にはできます。配列どうしなら結合はできますよね

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。おっしゃる通り、正しくは「各々のDogに紐づいているRegistrationNumbersを表示したい」です。
`@dog = @dog.to_a`してmergeを使ってやってみます

Answer (score 1, accepted):

コメントから察するに以下のような事をやりたいのだと解釈しました。
雑なサンプル考えたのでコメントではなく、回答欄に書きますね。

コントローラ

```rb
@dogs = Dog.where(user_id: current_user.id)
@registration_numbers = RegistrationNumber.where(dog_id: @dogs.ids)
```

View

```ruby
@dogs.each do |dog|
  p dog
  @registration_numbers.select {|rn| dog.id == rn.dog_id}.each do |registration_number|
    puts registration_number
  end
end
```

ActiveRecord::Relationと配列を結合したいシーンはあまり一般的ではないかと思っています。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
勉強になります。@registration_numbersの取得の仕方はともかく、Loopを二重に回すのはとてもおしゃれな感じがします。

Comment: 取得の仕方はおっしゃるとおりですね。効率とかあまり考えてないで書きました